# Unable to generate derived image located at public://

Tags: 8, media

I am trying to use a slideshow on my server and I get this error

```
Date    Monday, January 28, 2019 - 18:28
User    Anonymous (not verified)
Location    http://mysite.dev.local/sites/default/files/styles/max_1920x1920/public/2019-01/Screenshot_2019-01-28_15-00-52_0.png?itok=xMdR5S3S
Referrer    http://mysite.dev.local/
Message     Unable to generate the derived image located at public://styles/max_1920x1920/public/2019-01/Screenshot_2019-01-28_15-00-52_0.png.
Severity    Notice
Hostname    127.0.0.1
```

My browser reports 500 Internal Server Error but the error.log shows nothing about the image even on LogLevel debug

Comment: Unwriteable file directory?

Comment: Which is the directory? I have in /var/www/mysite a tmp and a files which are both 777 and I have in web/sites/default a directory files which is 777 too. First two are empty tho. Image upload was not complained it only complains on the style generated images (max_1920x1920 ect). web/sites/default/files/2019-01 contains the uploaded images...

Comment: If it is complaining about the large sizes, it might be an out of memory error.  These sometimes don't get reported.  Also check your status report for access problems or missing graphical libraries.  Finally, the style images are generated in the style/<style_name>/public/<path to file> directories.  Make sure none of these are marked R/O for some reason.

Comment: Even with 777 it wont work if you have the wrong folder owner/group name.